# Validar $mail->AddAddress - PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Como puedo validar si el objeto `$mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);` está recibiendo un correo valido, porque me ocurre que si envio un correo con un formato no valido ejemplo usuario@.dominio.com, el phpmailer me genera un error y me detiene el proceso de envio, estoy haciendo un envio multiple de una bases de datos y lamentablemente no puedo reparar todos los correos por lo que necesito una validación que me verifique el correo y si este es valido ejecutar la funcion `$mail->Send()` si no es valido que no me detenga el proceso para ejecutar con el siguiente correo.

A continuación el codigo del error:

```html
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' with message 'Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.' in /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la funcion [`filter_var`](https://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php)

Ejemplo

```
if(filter_var('usuario@.dominio.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "email valido";
} else {
    echo "email invalido";
}
```

Lo ideal, obviamente es que el front se encargue de validar el email al cual intentas enviar un correo, pero esta sería una buena forma de validar antes de que PHPMailer te devuelva un error.

De todas maneras podrias usar `try` `catch` para poder capturar el error.

```
try {
  $mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);
  $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero por ejemplo este email "-user@domain.com" es detectado como valido por el codigo y phpmailer procede a enviarlo y me genera un crash que me detiene el envio de multiples correos. Lamentablemente con ese codigo no me funciona para todos los casos.